# SQL Keys, Foreign Keys a bit too locked down for purposes

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm not sure if this is supported but

```
table1           table2
id               id
user1            sender
user2            receiver
```

So I want all of id, user1, user2 to be the foreign key for table2, nothing can get insert to table 2 unless that tuple is met. But I want it to be so sender and receiver can be either or for user1, user2.

So I tried foreign keys but of course that'll only allow the one order. (id, sender, receiver) references table1(id, user1, user2)

Is there any way I can do this?
Thanks for even reading haha. This is stressing me.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want this unorthodox structure?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest simplifying your schema to the following:

```
table1 (user_id)
table2 (id, sender, receiver)

    sender   --> user_id
    receiver --> user_id
```

The only foreign key relationship which needs to exist is that *both* the sender and receiver exist as a primary key in the user table, somewhere.

Comment: I had it done like that initially, but I'm just playing with it at this stage. I was just wondering is it possible. But thank you.

Comment: It might be _possible_ to enforce this via a trigger, but the bigger question is why do you need it?  What about your initial design (or my answer) fails to meet some requirement?

Comment: Well there will be no application layer. It's just for a little showcase, a class project. There are no requirements, really. Could you give me some idea of how I might use a trigger? I can run with whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that `table1` contains pairs of users who are allowed to communicate to each other and `table2` has the actual communications, if any.

If this is the case, I would suggest:

```
create table1 (
    table1_id int auto_increment primary key,
    user_id1 int not null,
    user_id2 int not null,
    unique (user_id1, user_id2),
    foreign key (user_id1) references users(user_id),
    foreign key (user_id2) references users(user_id)
);

create table2 (
    table2_id int auto_increment primary key,
    sender_user_id int not null,
    receiver_user_id int not null,
    foreign key (sender_user_id, receiver_user_id) references table1 (user_id1, user_id2),
    foreign key (sender_user_id) references users(user_id),
    foreign key (receiver_user_id) references users(user_id)
);
```

Then, the key idea is that PAIRs are inserted into table1:

```
insert into table1 (user_id1, user_id2)
    values (1, 3), (3, 1);
```

If you like, you could set up a trigger for this purpose, but that seems like overkill.